# Python String format with dynamic key throws KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
import re

regex = r"\{(.*?)\}"

v = '2020-01-21'
x = "xdate({date1}, 'mm/dd/yyyy')"

yy = x.format(date1=v)
print(yy) 
#works as expected

m1 = re.search(regex, x)
if m1:
    p1 = m1.group(0)
    #p1 = m1.group(1)    
    print(p1)
    p = x.format(p1=v)
    print(p)
```

In the above program, I can get it to work when I print **yy** but I do not want to hard code the string literal **date1**, I am trying to read the string literal and use it in `format()`

I am receiving `KeyError: 'date1'`. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positional placeholder `{}` instead of named ones.

So instead of:

```
x = "xdate({date1}, 'mm/dd/yyyy', {date2}, 'dd/mm/yyyy', {date3}, 'yyyy/mm/dd')"
yy = x.format(date1=v1, date2=v2, date3=v3)
```

do:

```
x = "xdate({}, 'mm/dd/yyyy', {}, 'dd/mm/yyyy', {}, 'yyyy/mm/dd')"
yy = x.format(v1, v2, v3)
```

Comment: Thank you, how does it work if we have more than one positional arg?

Comment: You can use multiple `{}`s in the format string. I've updated the answer accordingly then.

Comment: Thanks again. I mean if we have ```xdate({date1}, 'mm/dd/yyyy', {date2}, 'dd/mm/yyyy', {date3}, 'yyyy/mm/dd')``` and if we use ```{}``` in place of date1, date2 and date3, how do we substitute with different values? sorry if you have already covered this in your answer but it was not clear to me.

Comment: It's actually the same thing. Use multiple `{}`s in the format string. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using Python 3.7, why not use `f-strings` to format the strings. It's arguably more readable and slightly faster too.

```py
import re

regex = r"\{(.*?)\}"

v = "2020-01-21"
date1 = v
x = f"xdate({date1}, 'mm/dd/yyyy')"

yy = x
print(yy)

m1 = re.search(regex, x)
if m1:
    p1 = m1.group(0)
    # p1 = m1.group(1)
    print(p1)
    p = x.format(p1=v)
    print(p)
```

This prints,

```py
>> xdate(2020-01-21, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```